# Linux kernel module softdeps that don't have pre: nor post: specified

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

CIFS has a softdep dependency generated by **kmod** in `/lib/modules/*/modules.softdeps` that goes like this:

```
softdep cifs gcm
softdep cifs ccm
softdep cifs aead2
softdep cifs sha512
softdep cifs sha256
softdep cifs cmac
softdep cifs aes
softdep cifs nls
softdep cifs md5
softdep cifs hmac
softdep cifs ecb
```

Looking at the source code in `fs/cifs/cifsfs.c` or `fs/smb/client/cifsfs.c` (kernel version 6.4 or newer), `pre:` nor `post:` is not specified.

```
MODULE_SOFTDEP("ecb");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("hmac");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("md5");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("nls");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("aes");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("cmac");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("sha256");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("sha512");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("aead2");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("ccm");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("gcm");
```

My question is how is this interpreted by modprobe or any tool that might parse `modules.softdep`?  Should it just be interpreted the same as having `pre:`?

In `fs/smb/server/server.c` (6.4), the dependencies are declared with `pre:` hinting the ones in `client/cifs/cifsfs.c` might have been intended to be `pre:`:

```
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: ecb");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: hmac");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: md5");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: nls");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: aes");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: cmac");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: sha256");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: sha512");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: aead2");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: ccm");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: gcm");
MODULE_SOFTDEP("pre: crc32");
```

But I want a definite answer to this.  The [code in libkmod-config.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kernel/kmod/kmod.git/tree/libkmod/libkmod-config.c?h=v30#n258) does not make it any apparent.  It seems to just ignore it, but that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: A few tips to those who might want to look into this: it might be intended to just show that `cifs` has those stuff as soft dependencies but aren't to be loaded in the manner of `modprobe a b c d e` where `c` is `cifs` and `a b`  are "pre" dependencies and `d e` are "post" dependencies.  So doing a `modprobe c` only does `modprobe c`.  There's also a possibility that those modules mentioned are expected to be builtin.  What still just majorly confuses me is how would that list even be helpful in anything.

Comment: something to shed light on it: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=3591bb83eee7731d3421621a3b04d2432f80bba0

Comment: @A.B Couldn't open the referred bug's page because of required authority. I'll just take it as a deliberate hack to prevent existing buggy modprobe installs from trying to load a builtin. Please convert your comment to an answer so I can give you the bounty.

Comment: Done. But hopefully somebody will come with a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

This was introduced in this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=3591bb83eee7731d3421621a3b04d2432f80bba0) probably around kernel 5.5:

> cifs: don't use 'pre:' for MODULE_SOFTDEP
>
> It can cause
> to fail with
> modprobe: FATAL: Module  is builtin.
>
> RHBZ: 1767094

However, this [bug is not publicly available](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1767094).

Testing by creating this file:

`/etc/modprobe.d/local-cifs.conf`:

```
softdep cifs pre: lzo xt_LED
```

where in my kernel `lzo` is built-in (as seen in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin`) and `xt_LED` is a module doesn't fail: `modprobe cifs` then loads `xt_LED` + `cifs`. So I wonder if this was a bug that was fixed and left an other bug around (without `pre:` or `post:` anywhere such `softdep` line has no effect) or if there's something else to know (a bit difficult when the reason is not available).

Comment: I wonder now if the error is not about when `cifs` is builtin and would pre-depends on modules instead.  But then this wouldn't have to be triggered by `modprobe`. Can't test this without additional efforts.